# How to filter a dataframe, by getting everything in a df, MINUS another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have this `pandas` dataframe:

```
data = [{'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 42}, {'Name': 'Adam', 'Age': 25}
         ,{'Name': 'Bill', 'Age': 65}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

q = df[df['Name'] == 'Tom']
```

How can I filter `df` to get all of the rows of the dataframe, *except* for, what I filtered in `q`

So it should return {'Name': 'Adam', 'Age': 25} and {'Name': 'Bill', 'Age': 65}.

Thanks!

Comment: Should return Adam or Tom?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can invert mask by `!=` for not equal:

```
new = df[df['Name'] != 'Tom']
print (new)
   Name  Age
1  Adam   25
2  Bill   65
```

Another idea is remove index values of `q` from original `DataFrame`, but it working well only if unique index values:

```
q = df[df['Name'] == 'Tom']
new = df.drop(q.index)
print (new)
   Name  Age
1  Adam   25
2  Bill   65
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use LOC and ~. It will help you to "filter" your DF

```
df = df.loc[~df.Name.isin(['Adam']),:]
```